# Preposition confusion - or, in, at, or for?

Tags: prepositions

A lot of debate going on the Facebook post for this.

[image]

To me, it **was** certainly *'in'*. But I **may** consider 'at' as well. I'm confused!

Why 'in'? Because you do degrees 'in' some subject/topic. 
Why 'at'? Because then you consider 'specializing....' as another clause supporting the 'law degree'. So, you specialize 'at' something!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is *in*.

For that example, the answer is definitely *in*, nothing else there would be even slightly correct. In English, the preposition relating to work is usually *in*, including for your second example with specialise.

For example:

> I work in engineering.
>
> I specialise in civil engineering.

In sentences like "*I work at a bar*", the preposition relates to the location of work, not the profession itself.